# Test Case Outcome Column in TFS 2010 and/or Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio, testing, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to figure out how to add the work item field Outcome to my queries in TFS 2010 and/or Test Manager 2010 so that I can see our test case results and use them for reporting purposes.

While I realize this column is available through the default reports provided by linking TFS to a SharePoint site, I am currently unable to set this up since our client hasn't configured their SharePoint to do it yet.

My current plan is to create my own reports within Excel, but to break my question down simply, is there anyway to query for this field from within TFS or Test Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there really isn't a way to access the Outcome field from TFS or Test Manager currently (up to TFS 2012 for sure).

The easiest way to do it for a project that doesn't have its reports setup (or for Visual Studio Online which doesn't have the test reports) is to do it manually from the results in Test Manager.

Thanks to everyone for viewing and for the help.